# How to get "while else" type logic for fetch_array?

Tags: php, sql, while-loop, fetch

I have this code:

```
while($m = $movieResult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
       // stuff happens here
}
return $stuff;
```

It works but What I really need is to detect when the while loop doesn't run like this example but with multiple iterations of the while loop:

```
if($m = $movieResult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
      // stuff happens here
      return $stuff;
}
else{
     return false;
}
```

Comment: note that ->fetch_array grabs a SINGLE row of result data. it doesn't grab the entire result set. this may be what you want, but given you've asked other questions with this bit of code, I'm pretty sure you're going to get invalid results.

Comment: That's true, I think I will simply create a variable set to false then if while loop runs I will change it to array and .= for each iteration.

Comment: .= is for string operations. array_push or the `$arr[] = ...` notation is more appropriate.

Comment: that's what I meant to say :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which extension you are using (pdo/msqli/...) but i think you can see if there are any results first before starting your loop

**Example:**

```
if ($movieResult->num_rows > 0){
    ... your while loop here
}else{
   return false;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid this since in a previous question I learned that checking before while loop is pointless. How is the "num_rows" check performance wise? If it's insignificant I can use it then.

Comment: performance wise? The *_num_rows methods do nothing but return the number of rows from the query.  If it is zero, then dont run the while loop, simple as that.

Comment: I see now, it seemed to me that to get number of rows there was another database call, seems silly now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$loopCount = 0
while(condition) {
    // stuff
    $loopCount++;
}
if ($loopCount > 0) {
    return $stuff;
}
return false;
```

Comment: Just after asking I realised that I could just set $stuff to false and update it in the while loop. Your method works too, thanks